# FLASK python SQL function to move ID from one DB table to another

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am building a simple movie recommendation app in Python with flask to try and teach myself some more programming. I am hitting a brick wall with the main function of the app, when I display a movie poster to the user, from my DB table StreamingTitles, and they like or dislike it with a pair of buttons. This adds the movies ID, tbdb_id in the DB table, to a column in the user table, liked_titles or disliked_titles. The idea being I can compare different users likes at a later date, and show the user their watch list. The function I am having issues with.

```
@login_required
@app.route('/movies', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def movies():
try:
# Get the next movie to be displayed
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM StreamingTitles ORDER BY id DESC"
cursor.execute(sql)
movie_data = cursor.fetchone()
if request.method == 'POST':
# Get the TMDB ID of the title
title_id = request.form['title_id']
# Get the user's ID from the session
user_id = session['username']['id']
# Determine whether the user liked or disliked the title
like_status = request.form['like']
# Update the user's liked/disliked titles based on like_status
if like_status == 'like':
sql = "UPDATE Users SET liked_titles = CONCAT(liked_titles, %s) WHERE id = %s"
else:
sql = "UPDATE Users SET disliked_titles = CONCAT(disliked_titles, %s) WHERE id = %s"
val = (',' + title_id, user_id)
cursor.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
flash("Rating submitted successfully")
# Get the next movie to be displayed
sql = "SELECT * FROM StreamingTitles ORDER BY id DESC"
cursor.execute(sql)
movie_data = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
return render_template('movies.html', movie_data=movie_data)
except mysql.connector.errors.InternalError as e:
print("Error in the movies function:", e)
db.rollback()
cursor.close()
return "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later."
```

The error I get is my "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later" as anticipated.

So from a bigger picture am I handling this in the right way? and if I am what did I mess up?

The structure of the database tables are, StreamingTitles:

[image: StreamingTitles]

[image: Users]

Comment: Please indent your code so we can read it